# program is unable to find the file

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i am trying to run a simple java program that reads from a file:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("weather.txt"));
    double prev = input.nextDouble();   // fencepost
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        double next = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(prev + " to " + next +
                ", change = " + (next - prev));
        prev = next;
    }
}
```

}
but i keep getting the following input:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: weather.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
at Files.test.main(test.java:9)
```

the file weather.txt is in the same folder as the .java program, and i am using eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the file weather.txt is in the same folder as the .java program, and i
>   am using eclipse kepler.

`src` directory is for `.java` files. You should place `weather.txt` on project directory of Eclipse Kepler workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this line

```
 System.out.println("current dir : " +  System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

just to see where the program is reading files from. You may then need to set the directory you are reading from relative to the class that is being run eg,

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("weather.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse Run Configuration allows you to set the directory where your program is running. Either set the directory accordingly, or use a path relative to the directory where you are running. This is usually the workspace directory.